# Visual Studio 2017 runsettings video capture settings, wmv 0 bytes

Tags: visual-studio, testing, devops, video-capture

Has anyone got this to work? I have not seen anything on this other than people having the issue of the video not being recorded. It is creating a wmv file of 0 bytes and a recordedmedia.trmx of 1 kb. any nuget package I am missing maybe?

```
<DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing DLL was Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.

Comment: where the DLL was placed to make this work?